# Bootstrap modal with a table opened from a table: layout issues

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Normally I do find solutions on stackoverflow or other sources, but in this case I'm in need of some assistance. In forehand appreciated!

I use bootstrap 2.3.2 and php.
I have a table with records from a mysql database. In the last column of the table, you have 3 icons so you can look at the complete record, you can edit it, and erase it.

I linked those icons to a bootstrap modal DIV, dynamically filled with the id of the record.
So every row has 3 divs for these 3 options:

```
<div id="LookupArtist<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">

<div id="DeleteArtist<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
```

Everything works fine, until I use a table in the modal div...
For the lookup of the complete record I added a dynamically filled table in that modal div.
Because the div is created within a cell of another table, the layout is broken, and the bootstrap modal won't open.

I understand that I must create the modal div with the table outside the other table, but then this div won't be part of the loop, and will not have an id called 'LookupArtist62'.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your table and modal divs in your php loop then echo them afterwards...

in pseudo code

```
<?php
$table = '<table>';
$modals = '';

start loop
  $table .= '<tr><td>your table content</td></tr>';
  $modals .= '<div id="LookupArtist'.$row['id'].' class="modal hide fade" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">your modal content</div>';
end loop

$table .= '</table>';

echo $table;
echo $modals;
?>
```

Comment: It's the perfect solution, Tims! I'm very grateful! It works like a charm!